# Configuring jqgrid search to search one of many

Tags: jqgrid

I'm having trouble either understanding or implementing search/filter functionality in jqgrid.

The data set is returned to the client with each item having a list of designers:

```
"IAConsultWorkflowRequestsList": [
    {
        "AppID": "ISP",
        "SubmittedDate": "12/13/2018",
        "IAAssigned": "<a style='color:blue !important;' href='mailto:Joseph@somewhere.com'><u>Joseph Kraft</u></a>",
        "IAAssignedName": null,
        "Status": "In Discovery",
        "SLA": 0,
        "DaysPassed": 157,
        "IsUserFM": false,
        "IsUserSecureEnv": false,
        "DesignParticipants": [
            {
                "Name": "John Kraft",
                "EmailAddress": "",
                "ID": "A2049"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Zack Adamas",
                "EmailAddress": "Zachary.Adamas@somewhere.com",
                "ID": "U6696"
            },
            {
                "Name": "David Kosov",
                "EmailAddress": "David.Kosov@somewhere.com",
                "ID": "U6644"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So in the 'Designers' column, I am concatenating the results to be comma separated, e.g.

John Kraft,
Zack Adamas,
David Kosov

And, if the item has an email address, the individual name is formatted as an email link:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:center;" title="John Kraft,Zack Burns,David Cosand" aria-describedby="workFlowIAGrid_DesignParticipants">
John Kraft,<br>
<a style="color:blue !important;" ref="mailto:Zachary@somewhere.com"><u>Zack </u></a>,<br>
<a style="color:blue !important;" href="mailto:David@somewhere.com"><u>David </u></a></td>
```

I have a select element with entries John, Zack, and David, but when I select one of the options, I do not get expected results.  If I select David, I would like to be shown any rows that contain David as one of potentially several names in the Designer column.

However, I am getting erratic behavior.  Some of the sopt options will cause something to happen, but not what is expected. None of the contains/not contained or in/not in options seem to do what I need.  What am I doing wrong?

Per Tony's comment, here is the grid init code:

```
$gridEl.jqGrid({
        xhrFields: {
            cors: false
        },
        url: "/IAConsult/GetWorkFlowIARequests",
        postData: {
            showAll: showAllVal,
            role: role,
            IsIAArchitect: userIsIA
        },
        datatype: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        loadonce: true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        sortable: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: '#workFlowIAGridPager',
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 50,
        autowidth: true,
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Design Participants', name: 'DesignParticipants', align: "center", formatter:commaSeparatedList },
            //same for other columns...
        ],
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var $myGrid = $(this),
                i = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
                cm = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
            return (cm[i].name === 'cb');
        },
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: true,
            root: "IAConsultWorkflowRequestsList"
        },
        beforeSubmitCell: function (rowid, name, value, iRow, iCol) {
            return {
                gridData: gridData
            };
        },
        serializeCellData: function (postdata) {
            return JSON.stringify(postdata);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            rowCount = $gridEl.getGridParam('records');
            gridViewRowCount = rowCount;
            var rowIDs = $gridEl.getDataIDs();
            var inCompleteFlag = false;
            //Filter code to apply filter in headers in MyWork grid
            var datatoFilter = $gridEl.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData').length == 0
                ? $gridEl.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")
                : $gridEl.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');
            var $grid = $gridEl, postfilt = "";
            var getUniqueNames = function (columnName) {

                var uniqueTexts = [],
                    mydata = datatoFilter,
                    texts = $.map(mydata, function(item) {
                        return item[columnName];
                    }),
                    textsLength = texts.length,
                    text = "",
                    textsMap = {},
                    i;

                if (texts[0] && texts[0].Name)
                    texts = $.map(texts,
                        function(item) {
                            return item.Name;
                        });

                for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
                    text = texts[i];
                    if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                        // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                        textsMap[text] = true;
                        uniqueTexts.push(text);
                    }
                }
                if (columnName == 'ConsultID') {
                    return (uniqueTexts.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }));
                } else return uniqueTexts.sort();
            }, buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
                var values = {};
                values[''] = 'All';
                $.each(uniqueNames,
                    function () {
                        values[this] = this;
                    });
                return values;
            }, setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
                var changedColumns = [];
                this.jqGrid("setColProp",
                    columnName,
                    {
                        stype: "select",
                        searchoptions: {
                            value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call(this, columnName)),
                            sopt: getSortOptionsByColName(columnName),
                            dataEvents: [
                                {
                                    type: "change",
                                    fn: function (e) {
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            //get values of dropdowns

                                            var DesignParticipant = $('#gs_workFlowIAGrid_DesignParticipants').val();
                                            //same for other columns...

                                            var columnNamesArr = columns.split(',');
                                            changedColumns.push(columnName);
                                            for (i = 0; i < columnNamesArr.length; i++) {
                                                if (true) {
                                                    var htmlForSelect = '<option value="">All</option>';
                                                    var un = getUniqueNames(columnNamesArr[i]);
                                                    var $select = $("select[id='gs_workFlowIAGrid_" + columnNamesArr[i] + "']");

                                                    for (j = 0; j < un.length; j++) {
                                                        var val = un[j];

                                                        htmlForSelect += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    $select.find('option').remove().end().append(htmlForSelect);

                                                }
                                            }

                                            $('#gs_workFlowIAGrid_DesignParticipants').val(DesignParticipant);
                                            //same for other columns...
                                        },
                                            500);
                                        //setting the values :
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
            };

            function getSortOptionsByColName(colName) {
                console.log(colName);
                if (colName === 'DesignParticipants')
                    return ['in'];
                else
                    return ['eq'];
            }

            setSearchSelect.call($grid, "DesignParticipants");
            //same for other columns...

            $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar",
                { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true });

            var localFilter = $gridEl.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
            if (localFilter !== "" && localFilter != undefined) {
                globalFilter = localFilter;
            }
            $gridEl.jqGrid("setGridParam",
                    {
                        postData: {
                             "filters": globalFilter,
                             showAll: showAllVal,
                             role: role,
                             IsIAArchitect: userIsIA
                        },
                        search: true,
                        forceClientSorting: true
                    })
                .trigger("reloadGrid");
            //Ending Filter code
            var columnNamesArr = columns.split(',');
            for (i = 0; i < columnNamesArr.length; i++) {
                if (true) {
                    var htmlForSelect = '<option value="">All</option>';
                    var un = getUniqueNames(columnNamesArr[i]);
                    var $select = $("select[id='gs_workFlowIAGrid_" + columnNamesArr[i] + "']");
                    for (j = 0; j < un.length; j++) {
                        val = un[j];

                        htmlForSelect += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
                    }
                    $select.find('option').remove().end().append(htmlForSelect);
                }
            }
        },

        // all grid parameters and additionally the following
        loadComplete: function () {
            $gridEl.jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(window).width(), true);
            $gridEl.setGridWidth(window.innerWidth - 20);
        },

        height: '100%'
    });
```

Here is the formatter I am using on the column:

```
function commaSeparatedList(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {

        let dps = [];
        _.forEach(cellValue, function (item) {
            let formatted = '';
            if (item.EmailAddress)
                formatted += '<a style="color:blue !important;" href="mailto:' +
                    item.EmailAddress +
                    '"><u>' +
                    item.Name +
                    '</u></a>';
            else formatted = item.Name;
            dps.push(formatted + ',<br/>');
        });

        let toString = dps.join('');
        return toString.substring(0,toString.length-6);
    }
```

And then the only other pertinent thing is that I used a function to return 'in' (or some other key - these are the options I said weren't apparently working in the initial post) if the column is named 'Design Participants', else equal for any other column:

```
setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
                var changedColumns = [];
                this.jqGrid("setColProp",
                    columnName,
                    {
                        stype: "select",
                        searchoptions: {
                            value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call(this, columnName)),
                            sopt: getSortOptionsByColName(columnName),
                            dataEvents: [
                                {...
function getSortOptionsByColName(colName) {
                console.log(colName);
                if (colName === 'DesignParticipants')
                    return ['in'];
                else
                    return ['eq'];
            }
```

Comment: It will be good if you post your grid configuration. The very important question is: where is search performed? - at server or at client side? Publishing your full jqGrid code will help. One more important question - which version of jqGrid is used? - commercial Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid ver <= 4.7

Comment: @TonyTomov I am using jqgrid_4.6.0_i18n.js & free-jqgrid_4.13.js.  We are doing this client-side, per the code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the underlying data (the DesignParticipants in the returned JSON above) did not match the selected string, since the data itself was an array.  I believed the filtering was based on the displayed text in the grid table, but, it was based on the underlying data.  So, I created a new property of the returned JSON that was a string, and the filtering worked as expected.